# How to insert data into MPI communicator?

Tags: python, openmpi, mpi4py

I have a Python script called `manager.py` starting some `worker`s written in C++ using the `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn` function from the `mpi4py` module. I can access the workers in the Python script with the returned communicator, which only contains the workers.

Is there a way to insert data from the Python script into the worker communicator? Something like `Scatter` but the data is comming from outside of the communicator. Later I need a vice versa function like `Gather` to get the data out of the communicator.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I stumbled over the `Iscatter` and `Igather` methods.

When you call a program with `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn` you create a new communicator, a so called `Intercomm`. That is because two groups are created. One containing all the manager processes and one for all the worker processes. An `Intercomm` is a communicator, which is capable of communicating between multiple groups.

`Iscatter` scatters data from the root process of one group to all processes of the other group.

`Igather` collects data from all processes of the other group to the group, where the root process is located.

Extra caution is necessary as this function calls are non-blocking. However they return a `request` object, which you have to wait on to make sure data transfer is finished. Otherwise you will provoke a segmentation fault.

Some documentations: [OpenMPI Iscatter for C++](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/man3/MPI_Iscatter.3.php), [OpenMPI Igather for C++](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/current/man3/MPI_Igather.3.php), [mpi4py Iscatter](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/mpi4py.MPI.Comm.html#mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Iscatter), [mpi4py Igather](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/mpi4py.MPI.Comm.html#mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Igather)